# Java method with 1 line of code

Tags: java

I not sure whether this question belongs to the code review section so i will post here for now.

I have an expression like following:

```
if(userIds.contains(currentUserId)){
     throw new Exception("Cannot delete self");
}
```

I want to make it to become more readable, so i put it like the following:

```
if(isDeleteOwnAccount(userIds, currentUserId)){
     throw new Exception("Cannot delete self");
}

private boolean isDeleteOwnAccount(Set<Integer>userIds, int currentUserId) {
    return userIds.contains(currentUserId);
}
```

Is it better? Because i might have some other checking so it will become less readable if i don't do so, on the other hand, method with 1 line of code, is it good?

Comment: I am also not sure the question belongs here; anyhow your gut feeling is right. There is nothing wrong with a one-line method.

Comment: As of Rev 2, this is not a good Code Review question, but it could become one. The problem is that you are asking about a practice in general (one-liner methods) with very little code for context (I'm not sure it's even real code, since you said it's "_like_ the following"). Please add enough context so that we can see where these inputs are coming from — ideally an entire method or an excerpt from the class. Also retitle the question to state the purpose of the code (deleting a user, with validation) rather than your concern about the practice (one-liner method). See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the context, or how the rest of the method looks like.

*With* the exception, it's clear, what the method does - but Exception messages shouldn't describe what the intention of the code is, right?

If you had something like

```
if(userIds.contains(currentUserId)){
     return false;
}
// perform deletion
return true;
```

The reader is not sure, what the purpose of the contains is. If I had to change something in that code, I'd ask myself: *"Why can't I delete the given user, if it is present in that map?"*. To be honest: I would have assumed, it would be the opposite: Only delete, if a userId is present aka "can't delete unknown users". To be really sure, I actually have to read through the code and check, what happens, if the given userid is present in the map. Or look at the annotations and check, who committed that and hope, he's still working for us or check, if there's a link to the issue tracker, where the requirements are described.

So, your descriptive method (or a well written test case) would have saved me a lot of time.

Just keep in mind: We devs often find us reading and analyzing and debugging a lot more than writing code. I have had implemented requirements, which took maybe an hour and the "figuring out what to do" took days. We read and try to understand code a lot more, not only because of bugs, but also to check, what the impact of our changes would be or where else we might have to change the code, to either fulfil the requirements or verify, that we do not break something else. If we try to be as clear as possible in the code, we can reduce that amount and can do more of the fun part: the coding.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

> method with 1 line of code, is it good?

in short: yes.

---

in long:

Your approach is good because it enhances readability which is the second most important aspect of our code (right after correctness).

Usually we also create "one line methods" to apply *single layer of abstraction* which means that a method should either do primitive operations *or* call other methods (in same class or at other objects aka "dependencies").

Beside the improved readability short methods can be moved easier 
to other classes if needed...

So when in doubt go for "one liner methods".

Answer (score 1):

Clean Code guides us to fail fast, the exception must be thrown when `currentUserId` is added to `userIds` what is - respectfully - earlier.

So the correct code is this:

```
​
```

A Exception is not the correct type for that. Use `IllegalArgumentException` or create a new Type like a

```
List userIds = Strangers(User owner);
userIds.addAll(markedUsers); // throw here if owner is part of markedUsers
```

throwing a `ArrayStoreException` .